# How to make query to a stdclass objecta to get a value from variable and make a sum with it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress table called wp_mgm_transactions with two text fields and several rows of records: MODULE and DATA.

In each field DATA i have this values/structure (is this a stdclass object?):
    {"id":"3","membership_type":"member","duration":1,"duration_type":"l","cost":"10.00","num_cycles":1,"role":"subscriber","default":"1","description":"Acesso a todos os conte\u00fados do site.","hide_old_content":"0","active":"1","sort":"3","trial_on":"0","trial_duration":"0","trial_duration_type":"d","trial_cost":"0.00"}

[image]

I need to make a query to get the sum of 'cost'of all the data in rows WHERE module = 'paypal'

i know how to do it, if the DATA field was a number field, it would like this:

```
$SumTotalData = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT sum(data) FROM wp_mgm_transactions WHERE module = 'paypal'");
```

But, with all the above data type field, i'm lost. Any help?
Thank you, 
nelson

Answer (score 0):

Would this fit your need?

$find = What your looking for
$resultlength = The length of the supposed result, in this case **10.00** is 5 characters long.
$text = What to search in

```
$find = 'cost'; 
$resultlength = 5;
$text = '{"id":"3","membership_type":"member","duration":1,"duration_type":"l","cost":"10.00","num_cycles":1,"role":"subscriber","default":"1","description":"Acesso a todos os conte\u00fados do site.","hide_old_content":"0","active":"1","sort":"3","trial_on":"0","trial_duration":"0","trial_duration_type":"d","trial_cost":"0.00"}';

$result = substr(strstr($text, $find), strlen($find)+3, $resultlength);    
echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi sman591. Thank you for the reply, but i edit my question and what i need is the sum of 'cost' of all rows where Module = paypal